# Issues When Trying to Obtain Client's IP Address using Spring Boot Rest

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, network-programming, ip-address

Using Spring Boot and Java 1.7 to obtain a client's IP Address from a HTTP GET Call via Spring Rest.

RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class IpFinderController {

    private HttpHeaders headers;

    private static final String[] IP_HEADER_CANDIDATES = { 
              "X-Forwarded-For", 
              "Proxy-Client-IP", 
              "WL-Proxy-Client-IP",
              "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR", 
              "HTTP_X_FORWARDED", 
              "HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP", 
              "HTTP_CLIENT_IP",
              "HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR", 
              "HTTP_FORWARDED", 
              "HTTP_VIA", "REMOTE_ADDR" 
    };

    public IpFinderController() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ipAddress", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getIpAddress(HttpServletRequest request)
            throws IOException {

        String remoteAddress = "";
        if (request != null) {
            remoteAddress = getClientIpAddress(request);
            System.out.println("IP Address: " + remoteAddress);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(remoteAddress, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    public static String getClientIpAddress(HttpServletRequest request) {
        for (String header : IP_HEADER_CANDIDATES) {
            String ip = request.getHeader(header);
            if (ip != null && ip.length() != 0 && !"unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
                return ip;
            }
        }
        return request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
}
```

I get this from stdout:

```
IP Address: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
```

But I get this from the REST Call (via Swagger):

Response Body:

```
no content
```

Response Code:

```
0
```

Response Header:

```
{
   "error": "no response from server"
}
```

When using curl from the command line:

```
curl -i -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:8080/ipservice/api/v1/ipAddress'
```

Received this output:

```
curl: (3) Port number ended with ' '
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
```

Question(s):

1. Why am I getting 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 and not getting this as real IP address (is it because the client is behind a proxy / router)?
2. Why did I get a no content when running it via "Try it out" button on Swagger?
3. Why from the curl do I have problems and why is it not in JSON format?
4. Are there any 3rd party open source libraries which can help obtain a client's IP Address via HTTP Request? (ideal clients would be command line, web browsers, and mobile apps whether Android or iOS)?